# How to have a precise map of a country with R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, country

I usually went to the site :
http://gadm.org
to find the contours of the country I wanted to plot with R.
But today, this website is closed, and I don't know how to proceed to have a really accurate map...

When I try :

```
library(maps)
map("world", xlim=c(15,23), ylim=c(45.5,49))
```

The contours of the country are not very accurate...

I try to find an other website which could give the contours, but I didn't find.

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) have some nice shapefiles.

Comment: Yes but I don't understand how to use it ! Can you guide me ?

Comment: Use package `maptools` to read in a shapefile. See `?readShapeSpatial` for instance, once you loaded package `maptools`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, let's say you want to plot France contours using data from Natural Earth:

```
# First download the data in your working directory
download.file("http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip", "countries.zip")
# Then unzip
unzip("countries.zip")
# Load maptools
library(maptools)
# Read in the shapefile
world <- readShapeSpatial("ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp")
# Plot France
plot(world[world$ADMIN=="France",1]) 
# Column 1 is the id column, column "ADMIN" contains the country names
```

Comment: It doesn't work : `world <- readShapeSpatial("ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp") `
`Erreur dans getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file`

Comment: Did you enter exactly the two preceding lines (download.file and unzip)? None of them throws an error?

Comment: No, I don't have error until this `world <- readShapeSpatial("ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp")`. I do the 'unzip' etap without problem, the file.zip is allready in a directory on my computer.

Comment: ... Then you didn't enter exactly the code... The reason I asked is because the error you got means it didn't find the file which is normal if the file was not unzipped in the working directory. Replace "ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp" with the actual path to this file.

Comment: ok but are the unzipped files (the content of the zip) also in your working directory? Is specifically "ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp" is your wd?

Comment: Let's do it differently: type `world <- readShapeSpatial(file.choose())`, then find your file and select it.